# (Collapsing)Toolbar title resets its position after Snackbar appearance

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-snackbar

I have a layout with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout` as root element.
Whenever a `Snackbar` is shown in the `activity` the `title` of the `toolbar` resets its position to the default expanded title position of the `CollapsingToolbar` even if the `toolbar` is not (fully) expanded.

The second picture shows that the `title` is fixed no matter if the `toolbar` expands or not.

[image: Fully expanded]

[image: After Snackbar was shown]

The result is the same when I call `snackbar.show()` in `activity` or `fragment`.

My layout structure looks like this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <Toolbar />
        <TabLayout />
    </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</AppBarLayout>
<ViewPager />
<FloatingActionButton />
```

I use the latest dependencies for `appcompat and design library (v24.2.1)`.
I hope that's enough information and somebody has an idea how to solve the issue :P

**EDIT:** 
Also in the template when you start a new project and choose `Scrolling activity` the same problem appears when `snackbar.show()`is called. So it's a library issue.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73592529 just so you see how Google works, two years since i created this issue

Comment: What `layout_scrollFlags` are you setting in your `CollapsingToolbarLayout`? Have a look at this, it might help https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and it was a library issue. On the latest version of design support library (25.0.0) is fixed. Use the following on your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this is happening again in 26.1.0 ... how the hell is that possible ??

Answer (score 1):

I know a workaround to solve this issue.

Put your **CoordinatorLayout** inside a FrameLayout. While showing snackbar, instead of passing coordinatorlayout's Id pass FrameLayout's Id.

```
<FrameLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rel_full"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>



Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rel_full), "SNACKBAR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try This (Kotlin) :
    val collapsingToolbar = findViewById<CollapsingToolbarLayout>(R.id.collapsing_toolbar)
            collapsingToolbar.title = " "
            val appBarLayout = findViewById<AppBarLayout>(R.id.appbar)
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(true)
            appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {
                var isShow = false
                var scrollRange = -1
                @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
                override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout, verticalOffset: Int) {
                    if (scrollRange == -1) {
                        scrollRange = appBarLayout.totalScrollRange
                    }
                    if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                        collapsingToolbar.title = "YOUR_TITLE" 
                        isShow = true
                    } else if (isShow) {
                        collapsingToolbar.title = " "
                        isShow = false
                    }
                }
            })
```