# CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed title has bad position

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a straight forward CollapsingToolbarLayout.
It works fine so far but if I collapse the toolbar the title's position isn't centered vertically.

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/appbar_header_height_expanded"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/placekitten_1"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Have a look on my screenshots, so you can see how it behaves at the two states.

[image: expanded toolbar]

Here is the collapsed Toolbar's problem with the title.

[image]

I have this in my BaseFragment to set my toolbar at the actual Fragment:

```
protected void setToolbar(View view, int resource, String title, String subtitle) {
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(resource);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
}
```

So I found out,..
If I show a Snackbar then the title jumps to the right position and the expand/collaps works fine! So any ideas why it works after showing a Snackbar?

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    Snackbar mySnackbar = Snackbar.make(view, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    mySnackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color));
    mySnackbar.show();
```

And content_frame.xml is the root layout for the main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your activity code and theme ? everything seems ok in your layout.

Comment: It is apparently a known issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140811. But I'd never face it.. do you use appcompat last version ?

Comment: The same layout works in one fragment, but in the other fragments don't. This is very confusing.Yes I use the latest 26.1.0.

Comment: Have you tried using android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" for AppBarLayout and app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" for Toolbar ? This is now the default themes provide by AS activity generator.

Comment: I changed to styles, but no effect

Answer (score 11):

The Problem is the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root `CoordinatorLayout`. Remove that attribute from the **root layout** and the title behaves well.

Answer (score 5):

I tried solution at the end of this link: http://www.solutionscan.org/43500-android and it worked for me...

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    collapsing_toolbar.post { collapsing_toolbar.requestLayout() }
}
```

The only difference is that I am using fragments and new navigation component...

Comment: This solution helped me too. Spent almost a day trying different combinations of `android:fitsSystemWindows`. Very unobvious.

Comment: @despectra I also do not completely understand why layout needs to be refreshed :(

Answer (score 1):

This is something about

> ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

It always get the one corresponding to the first fragment so for the others it didn't work.
(I be able to reproduce the bug only when I changed to toolbar id to a wrong one, and that's explain why you dont have problem on one of your fragment)

Try to set a specific id for each Toolbar component in your different fragment layouts, or if the **layout.xml** is the same for all fragments, find a way to be sure to **setSupportActionBar** with the exact Toolbar view of your current fragment.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip, but I think there is nothing wrong with that, because I tried already to give a different toolbar-id for all different fragments and it changes nothing. I have for every view a different layout.xml with a different toolbar inside. But I will check it again

Comment: so problem appears when you use setSupportActionBar more than one time ?

Comment: No.., Look setSupportActionBar works basically fine, I have 1 Activity and about 10 Fragments. All Fragments works fine with there own layout.xml and every layout.xml works fine with it own specific toolbar. One CollapsingToolbarLayout works also fine, but the other ones doesn't work fine, they have the given issue. I don't know when the problem appears. If I knew that then I wouldn't have this problem hehe

Comment: I found out when it appears, problem still there, have a look to the edited question.

Comment: its a known issue: [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661995/collapsingtoolbar-title-resets-its-position-after-snackbar-appearance)

Comment: ouah such a mess.. May the snackbar provoc the requestLayout on CoordinatorLayout like it is mentioned here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140811#comment5

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i tried it with calling requestLayout, but no effect. There is also a new version of support library 27.0.0. I updated the version but no effect, Bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Add line android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to toolbar aswell.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```